Is there a way to adjust the height of a text content control in MS Word through VBA?
I have VBA code that creates a table dynamically depending on user selections in MS Word. The table will have content controls in them to ensure proper formatting. However, the content controls are too tall for the row height, and so they partially cover the cells underneath them that may also contain content controls. Is there a way when creating those controls to limit their height so that there is no overlap?
I have tried the .SetHeight function that should be a part of all objects, but it gave me the error of method not found. I haven't been able to find any other writable properties or methods referring to height.

Maybe you could include the code you are using in your question (not in a comment)? That would probably help.

A screenshot is helpful to understand the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol  there's no SetHeight method for ContentControl

@braX I didn't include code because I was looking for the property to adjust. Black Cat was able to get me in the right ballpark and I was able to figure it out from there.

@Tim I was under the impression that like most OOP, objects would inherit properties and methods from parent objects, with 'object' being the highest level one. It seems that is not part of VBA.

You can adjust row height of the content control something like this:
set my= activedocument.ContentControls(1)
my.range.paragraphformat.linespacing=1


Thank you for turning me on to the ParagraphFormat object. I needed to set the SpaceAfter property to 0.
